# What do I need to know before I *try* to install a Debian package on Fedora?

Tags: installation, opensuse, packages, fedora-15

I found this color picker package, [gpick](http://code.google.com/p/gpick/), reviewed in a random [blog](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/05/gpick-easy-to-use-color-picker-for.html). It uses GTK+ so I think I can use it on Fedora. Unfortunately there is not yum package in the normal repositories. There is an [OpenSUSE](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=home%3Aketheriel%3Agpick) repository that reports to have the package, but I've never used OpenSUSE distro packages on my Fedora distro. Not sure what to make of it.

What do I need to know before I try to install this from the maintainer's source or from the OpenSUSE repository?

Comment: Although built by openSUSE build service, the packages are designated for Fedora, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the package conversion is not going to be the easiest or most practical way to do it. Instead, you should set up the software from source. [This website has some instructions](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html) for general linux installs from source.